# Low overhead Java Web Services container?

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, jax-ws, cxf

I want to provide a Java-based Web Service, but I don't require the features of a full-blown J2EE Application Server.  I would like it to start as quickly as possible, though that's not a hard requirement.  The Web Service will handle multiple connections and require access to an Oracle database so it will at least require a thread pool and database connection pool.  I may want to put a JSP interface onto it later to provide an internal maintainence interface.

I have looked at Jetty with an Apache CXF stack, but it looks like I'll have to do a fair amount configuration before even coding the web service - Will it be worth it?  Will it even work?  Should I forget about the complexity and simply go with JBoss/Weblogic/etc and put up with the bloat and extra start-up time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with JAX-WS RI on Jetty, Tomcat or GlassFish v3 (I do **not** agree with other opinions expressed here and according to my *practical* experience with GFv3, GFv3 offers a highly productive environment for development).

And please, don't go Axis 2 (I won't even talk about its architecture and horrible deployment model and packaging hell, just  have a look at the [JAX-WS RI 2.1 benchmark details](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/02/jaxws_ri_21_ben.html)).

Comment: Ah, that sounds encouraging - I can happily use the JAX-WS built into JDK 6 rather than a 'custom' WS stack?  Does that cover WS-* though?

Comment: @trojanfoe JAX-WS RI implements WS-I Basic Profile 1.1, Simple SOAP Binding Profile 1.0 and Attachment Profile 1.0. If you want end-to-end message-level security then you'll need the WSIT layer
of Metro (Metro = JAX-WS RI + WSIT). See http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=44110 for more details.

Comment: So I am looking at Jetty + Metro to meet my requirements?  What about the database connection pool?  Is that standard with Jetty?

Comment: @trojanfoe Jetty does support connection pooling, see [DataSource Examples](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/DataSource+Examples). But I still think you should give GFv3 a try ;)

Comment: I will try Jetty + Metro first and then if I have problems I will try glassfish 3.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setting up Tomcat 6 + Axis 2 is [fairly easy](http://codediaries.blogspot.com/2009/02/setting-up-axis2-with-tomcat-6.html). I wouldn't recommend using JBoss/Glassfish/etc for your scenario - the overhead far outweighs the only benefit - no additional setup involved.

Comment: Are tomcat and axis 2 low overhead?  I have heard that axis 2 at least isn't a good performer?

Answer (score 1):

I am using embedded jetty for exposing a number of jax-ws webservices. Works pretty well, and configuration involved just stripping off things I didn't need from jetty.

Comment: So you are using the jax-ws built into JDK 6 or some other stack?  What did you strip off?

Comment: jax-ws 2.1.4 but most of its components are now in jkd yes. I stripped of jsp stuff etc from jetty.